# jQuery - Java Pre Roll AD over Flash from CPMStar giving issues in IE Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, conflict

My Site is: http://butplaygames.com

Here is the code i am putting in my footer right before the body tag:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
(function(i,w,d,p,c,e,s,t){t=d.getElementsByTagName('script');if(!w[i]){w[i]={ads:[]};s=d.createElement('script');s.src='http'+(d.location.protocol=='https:'?'s://server':'://cdn')+'.cpmstar.com/cached/js/global_v100.pack.js';s.type='text/javascript';s.async='';t[0].parentNode.insertBefore(s,t[0]);}
p['poolid'] = myidherewhichiput;
c['background'] = null;
c['close'] = null;
c['type'] = 'game';
w[i].ads.push({params:p,config:c,events:e,overlay:-1,s:t[t.length-1]});})('cpmstar',window,document,{},{},{});
//-->
</script>
```

My game embed code for flash:

```
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab" width="800" height="600" id="TreasureTrash">
<param name="movie" value="MYURL" />
<embed src="MYURL" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" wmode="opaque" width="800" height="600" name="TreasureTrash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
</embed></object>
```

The code works in Firefox, Chrome and Opera. But not in IE. Kindly help. I am very lost here. My site is butplaygames.

An AD is supposed to show over my flash games using the javascript code. It shows in Opera, Firefox and Chrome. But does not show in IE. IE does not even show any errors. It just makes the entire swf into a small dot and does nothing.

Comment: You might want to change the "java" tag to "javascript" so the right people will view the question. Just a little heads-up :)

Comment: Missed that... thx. Now fixed.

Comment: An AD is supposed to show over my flash games using the javascript code. It shows in Opera, Firefox and Chrome. But does not show in IE. IE does not even show any errors. It just makes the entire swf into a small dot and does nothing.

Comment: I wonder if we could use jQuery.noConflict() here? or if it is the way my flash game is embedded?

Answer (score 0):

The script needs to read the .swf from the src atribute. In your case, in the src atribute there is no .swf there.